# How can I customize fonts and backgrounds for gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, usability

Mac has background-color -theme adjusting. During summer, I realize why it would be so super-cool: it is hard to see anything with standard settings when there are so much sun-light. So how can I adjust the background-color settings and font similarly to Mac console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*gnome-terminal* is extensively customizable. Go to `Edit...Profile Preferences`, and you can change the following:

1. **Fonts**

   [image]
2. **Colors**

   [image]
3. **Backgrounds** (color, transparency and even a "wallpaper")

   [image]

As for saving and setting custom themes, they're just called Profiles here. You can save, switch and set the default from `Edit...Profiles`:

[image]

Comment: +1 ...yes and then just "Terminal > Change profile", worked well. Thank you. I created just inverse colors from Black/Background and White/font to White/Background and Black/font, much better during sunny time.